#  overriding default behaviour of backBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I am facing an issues with navigating between the views, Basically I have 3 views:

1. RootView
2. view1
3. View2

What I want to do is when I click on back button of `View2` I want RootView to be loaded instead of loading view1 (which is default).

.. I have written the below code in My view1.m before pushing the view2ViewController, code:

```
 UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" target:self action:@selector(someMethod:)];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = back;
-(void)someMethod:(id)sender{ [self.navigationViewCOntroller popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES] }
```

The above code is not working

Comment: Don't get the problem, didn't you just say that both view1 and view2 gets popped? Isn't it your goal?

Comment: Yeah.., Thats what I thought.., But it isnt happening

Answer (score 0):

The second half of your question is not clear.

Try this
`[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Hope this will work for you. By this you can navigate from View2 to your root view.

Comment: May be the second half of my ques is confusing to all.., So I have removed ..it... Thanks will check your suggestion

Comment: Please dont use kiddie text speak.

Comment: My apologies for being insulting which was unnecessary. My point is that if you are are going write an answer take the time to write in correct english. It helps everyone who visits SO looking for an answer especially those who dont read english well.

Comment: Whatever !!... I dont mind at all..
Somehow, the action Method set is not getting called.., But the button is displayed in the View2 with title "back to RootView" which I had set in view1's viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

To go to a View:

```
Aview *aview =[[Aview alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    settings.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    [self presentModalViewController:settings animated:YES];
```

To go back:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

So in ur case its:

```
-(void)someMethod:(id)sender{ 
 Rootview *rootview =[[Rootview alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        settings.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
        [self presentModalViewController:settings animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: But, In my case.., the "someMethod" action is not getting called...
But I am able to change the text of the backBarButtonItem as "back to RootView".. I am doin all these changes in view1's viewDidLoad..., as backBarButtonItem needs to be configured in previous view